# How to list the newest 10 posts using liquid?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, jekyll-bootstrap

I establish my Blog with the help of [jekyll bootstrap](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/) and deploy it on [github](https://github.com). Here is my question:
I want to add a sidebar which lists my newest 10 posts. When I use the code below, it lists all my posts:

```
<ul>
   {% for post in site.posts %}
       li><a href="{{ BASE_PATH }}{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

BUT, I only want to list the newest 10 posts(if the num of all posts less than 10, list all)，how can I do?
Thank You for your answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have the environment to test it, but you might want to try `limit` keyword, see [documentation here](http://wiki.shopify.com/Liquid). I assume it will show all if limit is not reached.

```
<ul>
   {% for post in site.posts limit:10 %}
       <li><a href="{{ BASE_PATH }}{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```